# Login failed for user 'adminUsr'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```vb
Dim sConnection As String = "Data Source = svr1066; Initial Catalog = 
    PFSEditTest;Integrated Security = true;"

Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
    Con.Open()
    Dim Com As New SqlCommand("Select * From PFSEEditTestTable WHERE ID = @ID", Con)
    Com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBoxID.Text)
   'Reading information from Database into Form
    Using Com
```

I'm trying to access a database and when I do a Server Log review says Error 18456, Severity 14, State: 38.  I looked up the codes and they mean user can fix and Login Valid but Database Unavailable with Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.  I'm able to run a query in SSMS against the database and it returns the information in the rows correctly.

Comment: The connection string refers to a datasource. That might be incorrect. Hard to tell.

Comment: www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: SELECT * FROM PFSEditTestTable entered as a SQL query against the Database PSFEditTest returns rows.  SQL can be such a challenge to debug.  Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: you are misusing `Using`.  `Using` is a combination of `Dim` and `New`.  You already did that to your `Com` object.  Trying to then use it as the target of a `Using` block will not close or dispose of it.  The point of them is to elide `Dim`, `New`, `Close` and `Dispose` in code

Comment: I see, ok.  I'm still so green at this.  Thanks for the great resource as well.  I appreciate it!

Comment: Try "Server=svr1066;Integrated Security=True;Database=PFSEditTest". Or check whether the database is configured to allow remote connections and the protocols that allowed (Named pipes, TCP/IP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error - the table isn't PFSEEditTestTable it should be PFSEditTestTable.  I also ended up publishing the application as available only online (through the server) which I like better because the users can just run it from the server and don't need it on their desktops.